# Local variables in Zend module

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-internals

I am writing a Zend module.
I have implemented this 2 functions:

```
   PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION
   PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION
```

The first one in called when a request is made. The second is called for the response.
I want to keep informations between the 2 functions.
I have tried to create a global variable but this variable is shared for all the PHP module. So other requests car interfere with it.

How can i store information into variables between thoses functions. The scope of those variables is the life of ONE php request

Comment: You can use a Zend Storage to do so.

Comment: Thanks can you tell me more ? How the variable scope could fit to request only

Comment: You should check official documentation : http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.storage.html. All the answers to your need are here. Zend_Storage is used to built session in zf2 but you can also built custom storage.

Comment: I am writing an extension with C. I am not in PHP layer...

Comment: Will a global variable be kept during the whole lifecycle? I've written several extensions but never used these hooks before so just a guess...

Comment: In fact i want a variable which will Be alive during script exécution and not shared between other scripts